Why am I getting "Assuming signed integer overflow does not occur" here?
Code in question (godbolt)
#include <stdbool.h>
void do_work(void);

typedef struct task {
    int timer;
    void (*job)(void);
} task_t;

typedef struct task_list {
    task_t *tasks;
    int length;
} task_list_t;

void test(task_list_t *task_list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < task_list->length; i++)
    {
        task_t *task = &task_list->tasks[i];
        __attribute__((assume(task->timer > 0)));
        task->timer--;
        bool timer_finished = task->timer <= 0;
        if (timer_finished)
            task->job();
    }
}

I get the following output:
<source>: In function 'test':
<source>:25:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when changing X +- C1 cmp C2 to X cmp C2 -+ C1 [-Wstrict-overflow]
   25 | }
      | ^
<source>:25:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when changing X +- C1 cmp C2 to X cmp C2 -+ C1 [-Wstrict-overflow]
Compiler returned: 0

Let's say I can't change task_t::timer to an unsigned type. Why is the assume being ignored? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the warning?

Given that violating the assumption would bestow the wonders of UB upon you, let's assume it holds. Then bool timer_finished = !task->timer; is an equivalent check that does not produce the warning.

Note that if task->timer > 0 then after the decrement, task->timer < 0 is not a possibility. If you change the code to  bool timer_finished = task->timer == 0; then the diagnostic goes away.

And wouldn't you need to pass task to job() so that it can set the new value of task->timer, since you can't leave it at 0?

@AviBerger it's a toy example. This warning occurred in a totally different context, this is just a minimal reproducible example I came up with.

The warning you're getting warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur [...] [-Wstrict-overflow] is due to the compiler letting you know it is assuming your integer variable task_t::timer won't ever be INT_MIN when decrementing (task->timer--;).
Decrementing the variable when already at its minimum value would cause an overflow (or underflow) which the C standard defines as Undefined Behaviour (UB).
The compiler assumes it won't overflow in order to optimize the resulting machine code. It's issuing a warning because, in optimizing the following:
bool timer_finished = task->timer <= 0;

it assumes that task->timer will not overflow. If it did, the comparison might behave unexpectedly due to UB.
The __attribute__((assume)) helps the compiler understand certain properties at a specific point but it does not affect assumptions about integer overflows across the code. The compiler still respects the C standard, which allows it to optimize with the assumption that signed overflow is UB.
To suppress the warning, you would need to make it clear to the compiler that the comparison will never be performed when a signed overflow is possible, e.g.:
if (task->timer > 0) {
    task->timer--;
    bool timer_finished = task->timer <= 0;
    if (timer_finished)
        task->job();
}

This makes sure that task->timer only decrements when it’s positive, avoiding potential underflow issues and making the compiler happier and not spit out a warning :)

I see, I would have expected the assume attribute to make the warning go away. In any case, thank you.

Wild guess... but I would say that the reason is that at some intermediate stage the comparison task->timer <= 0 is being moved by the compiler before the decrement, changing it to task->timer <= 1.
If you declare an external function void foo(void); and call foo() after the decrement but before the test you will notice that the warning disappears (in that case propagating the decrement operation to the comparison would not be legal as foo() could have changed the field value).
